# ransac with homography vs 8/5 point algorithms

Tags: computer-vision

Im beginning to learn computer vision and I'm confused on the difference between the two.

I know that the 8 point algorithm is used to compute the fundamental matrix and the 5 point algorithm is used to compute the essential matrix.  Both of which can be used to determine the relative camera pose.

I also found that the relative camera pose can be determined using ransac with homography https://inspirit.github.io/jsfeat/#multiview in the ransac method

Is there a difference between using ransac with homography as opposed to using the algorithms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, note that you still need RANSAC with the 8-point or 5-point algorithms, since in practice outliers are to be expected in the matching process.

I think the main downside of pose from homography is that the point matches you use need to be coplanar. Additionaly, if I'm not mistaken, in  a scene with more than one plane, you might get different homographies depending on which planes you select in the scene. That is why applying a homography to correct perspective adds distortion to some other parts of the image (see the example in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fVJeJMWZcq8) video). So in complex scenes (*e.g.* urban environements) where matching is more difficult, I'd use one of the 8-point or the 5-point algorithms.

Note that you can also recover the relative pose directly (up to scale, obviously), and compute the essential from that (see [this paper](http://www.bmva.org/bmvc/2013/Papers/paper0116/paper0116.pdf)). It's easier than computing the fundamental/essential and then extracting relative pose.